# rails 3 has_many through has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Suppose you have the following models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :current_heat, class_name: 'Heat'
  has_many :scores, :through => :current_heat
end

class Heat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :scores
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :heat
end
```

Surprisingly, when I invoke `Category.first.scores` ActiveRecord produces the following queries:

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `scores` INNER JOIN `heats` ON `scores`.`heat_id` = `heats`.`id` WHERE `heats`.`category_id` = 1
```

The above query ignores the has_one nature of `Category#current_heat`. I would have expected something more like:

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` LIMIT 1
SELECT `heats`.* FROM `heats` WHERE `heats`.`category_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `scores` WHERE `scores`.`heat_id` = 6
```

which is produced only when you explicitly traverse the has_one association from the root with `Category.first.current_heat.scores`.

It's as if ActiveRecord is silently treating my has_one as a has_many. Can someone explain this behavior to me? Is there an elegant workaround or a "right way" to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could remove the

```
has_many :scores, :through => :current_heat
```

and instead just delegate :scores through the has_one:

```
delegate :scores, :to => :current_heat
```

that would preserve your desired access method Category.first.scores.

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` doesn't really exist to babysit your database in this fashion.  It won't throw errors if there is more than one record that matches the foreign_key, it will just choose the first one.  It assumes you haven't errantly added extra records which would break the `has_one` relation on your own.

In conclusion, the sql that it generates is fine as long as there is only one record attached to the Category.  If somehow you've added extra records which shouldn't exist since it is a `has_one`, then it won't work, but it's not the job of activerecord to tell you that this has happened.

Comment: There will definitely be more than one row per category in heats, but its okay because I've added a `default_scope order('created_at DESC')` to Heat to ensure that any time I'm talking about Heat a singular sense, it's the most recent heat. In that way, I have the flexibility of talking about heats both currently and historically. So in a sense its both has_many and has_one, depending on the use case.